# How to make my Ubuntu/Apache2 (Using Nodejs and Expressjs) server use the server's localhost instead of the user's localhost?

Tags: node.js, express, apache2, ubuntu-20.04

I'm new to Ubuntu and Apache.

When I CRUD through Express, instead of using the server´s localhost, server/browser will use my computer's localhost.

If I turn off Express server in localhost, the server's get, post and delete don't work, and I can't seem to find a way to use the server's localhost instead of my computer's.

I've also tried sending my requests to:

```
http://localhost:8383/decrypted
http://127.0.0.1:8383/decrypted
```

The routes above throw an error as they are http and server is https.

```
https://example.com/8383/decrypted
```

The route about throws error connection refused

```
https://example.com/8080/decrypted
```

I tried adding a virtualhost in 8080 and routing it through apache to 8383, but shows the same error as above, connection refused.

How can I make the server use its localhost instead of the user's localhost?